# Setting Output Data Type in ArcPy GDAL

Tags: python, arcpy, gdal, arcgis-pro, gdal-translate

I'm using ArcPy through a notebook in ArcGIS Pro 2.9.3. I'm trying to use `gdal.Translate` and `gdal.TranslateOptions` to translate a .tif file to a 32 bit signed integer .rst file. I've been able to set it up fine, but I don't understand what format to have the `outputType` argument as in `gdal.TranslateOptions`.
My code so far is:

```
# Import modules
import arcpy
import glob
import os
import collections
from osgeo import gdal
from osgeo.gdalconst import * #unsure if this module or the next are necessary, but found within gdal.py lines 115 and 116
from osgeo import gdalconst

#setting options
options = gdal.TranslateOptions(format='GTiff', outputType="gdalconst.GDT_Int32")
```

This code returns the message:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
In  [63]:
Line 4:     options = gdal.TranslateOptions(format='GTiff', outputType="gdalconst.GDT_Int32")

File C:\Users\orang\AppData\Local\ESRI\conda\envs\arcgispro-py3-clone-1\Lib\site-packages\osgeo\gdal.py, in TranslateOptions:
Line 381:   new_options += ['-ot', GetDataTypeName(outputType)]

File C:\Users\orang\AppData\Local\ESRI\conda\envs\arcgispro-py3-clone-1\Lib\site-packages\osgeo\gdal.py, in GetDataTypeName:
Line 4076:  return _gdal.GetDataTypeName(*args)

TypeError: invalid value for GDALDataType
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I've also tried supplying `outputType` with `'GDT_Int32'` and `'Int32'`, but they provide the same error message.
What format of Int32 will make it a valid value?

Documentation that I've used:

- https://gdal.org/programs/gdal_translate.html
- https://gdal.org/python/osgeo.gdal-module.html#Translate
- https://gdal.org/python/osgeo.gdal-module.html#TranslateOptions

Comment: If you are using arcpy, why not use the [Copy Raster](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/tool-reference/data-management/copy-raster.htm) tool which will work in arcpy as its an esri tool, no need to be calling GDAL directly. A lot simpler...

Comment: Pass in `GDT_Int32` (a variable imported from `osgeo.gdalconst`), not `"gdalconst.GDT_Int32"` (a string)

Comment: `outputType=gdalconst.GDT_Int32` not `outputType="gdalconst.GDT_Int32"`